# changing format date in excel using formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have a excel with date format as " **Feb  1 2020  1:00AM** "

I am trying to convert this format to " **08-10-2019  10:27:50 "**

I have tried using text formula but date format remains same its not changing.

Answer (score 1):

`Feb 1 2020 1:00AM` is not a date format that Excel recognizes and as such it is a text string and not a number that can be reformatted.

One needs to parse the string to something that Excel will recognize: `1 Feb 2020 1:00 AM`

This formula parses the string and turns it into a number that can be formatted as desired:

```
=--REPLACE(TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&{2,1,3,4}&"]")),LEN(A1)-1,0," ")
```

Then format the date either: `mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss` or `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` depending on locale.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the details. but im getting error as #NAME?  copy pasted your formula as =--REPLACE(TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&{2,1,3,4}&"]")),LEN(A1)-1,0," ")

Comment: @Narens then your version does not have TEXTJOIN.